# Overlay columns of histograms with scatter plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to visualize a data set and I'm stuck pretty early in the process because I don't understand the logic of matplotlib.

The data is kept in two 2d tables of the same format:

```
>>> data1
array([[  1.        ,   1.384     ],
       [  2.        ,   3.65218531],
       [  3.        ,   3.17718531],
       [  1.        ,   2.34513543],
       [  2.        ,   3.43223443],
       [  3.        ,   1.23333255],
        ...
>>> data2
        ...
```

I want to visualize these tables in the same plot. The `data1` table has many more rows than `data2`, so my idea is to display `data1` with column-wise histograms and `data2` with points like this:
[image: Example]

I know how to make 1D histograms of data, and I know how to make scatterplots, but how do I get colored bins and overlay them with the scatterplots in the right positions?

Edit:
Example code:

```
import pylab
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
data1 = numpy.array([[1,1.5],[2,1.7],[3,1.8],[1,1.2],[2,1.8],[3,2.2]])
data2 = numpy.array([[1,2.1],[2,1.3],[3,1.4],[1,1.1],[2,1.9],[3,2.25]])

plt.scatter(data1[:,0], data1[:,1])
plt.scatter(data2[:,0], data2[:,1], color="red")
plt.show()
```

In the real code the `data1` array contains so many entries that it becomes a mess. Hence the wish for a 'histogram'.

Comment: can you explain your data format in a little more detail and give us some copy/paste-able code to create a toy version of it? where specifically are your `x`, `y`, and `z` values? lastly, can you show use what you've tried already?

Comment: I added an example with what I've been doing so far.

Comment: `imshow` with the extent kwarg will do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
w = .2
bins = np.linspace(-4, 4, 11, endpoint=True)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for j in range(1, 15):
    tt = randn(50)

    nn, _bins = np.histogram(tt, bins)
    #  don't use scatter unless you need to change the size or color of the markers
    ax.plot(j*np.ones_like(tt), tt, 'r.')
    ax.imshow(nn.reshape(-1, 1)[::-1], extent=[j-w, j+w, -4, 4], cmap='Blues', aspect='auto', interpolation='none')


ax.set_xlim([0, 15])
ax.set_ylim([-4, 4])
```

It might be better to draw each bin as a `Rectangle`.

You probably also want to use the `vmax` and `vmin` kwargs for `imshow` so that the colors have the same meaning between columns.

[image]

Comment: Wow theres a lot of new things for me here. `linspace` works as `range` but for floats, `reshape(-1,1)` transposes an array, and `[::-1]` reverses the entries of a column. I have a lot of respect for python and numpy/matplotlib but _man_ the learningcurve is steep sometimes.

Comment: `reshape(-1, 1)` does not transpose an array, it is a poor way to turn a `(n, )` array (1D, length n) into a `(n, 1)` (2D, n elements, (nx1))

Comment: Well .. you can consider an array of length n a 1xn matrix and it gets transformed into a nx1 matrix while maintaining the components and their order .. thats a transposition. But you're right, this might be a confusing choice of word since reshaping involves changing types as well. In any case, thanks a bunch for the beautiful solution, its just what I wanted.

Comment: @Fonseca Sorry for the very late reply, but `(n, )` and `(1, n)` shaped arrays are different things.